# Searching file for a string in the first field depending on the input from another file and piping the result to new file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, field, piping

I have an input file like below

```
 Model related text
 Model specifications
 *ELEMENT_SHELL
 $#   eid     pid   n1   n2   n3   n4   n5   n6      n7    n8
 76737    1    79322  79323   79324   79511     0       0       0       0
 76738    1   79510   79203   79204   79512     0       0       0       0
 76739    1   79511   79324   79325   79513     0       0       0       0
 76740    1   79512   79204   79205   79514     0       0       0       0
 76741    1   79514   79205   79206   79515     0       0       0       0
 76742    1   79515   79206   79207   79516     0       0       0       0
 76743    1   79516   79207   79208   79517     0       0       0       0
 76744    1   79517   79208   79209   79518     0       0       0       0
 76745    1   79518   79209   79210   79519     0       0       0       0
 76746    1   79519   79210   79211   79520     0       0       0       0
```

In another file File 2 I have only numbers like

```
 76737    
 76738    
 76739    
 76740    
 76741
```

I have to compare these each numbers from File2.txt with the numbers in the first line of the File1.txt and if it matches, the complete line from File1.txt would be output to model.txt
The output would be

```
 Model related text
 Model specifications
 *ELEMENT_SHELL
 $#   eid     pid   n1   n2   n3   n4   n5   n6      n7    n8
 76737    1    79322  79323   79324   79511     0       0       0       0
 76738    1   79510   79203   79204   79512     0       0       0       0
 76739    1   79511   79324   79325   79513     0       0       0       0
 76740    1   79512   79204   79205   79514     0       0       0       0
 76741    1   79514   79205   79206   79515     0       0       0       0
```

can anybody suggest me with AWK, SED etc?

Comment: Investigate using join...

Comment: actually I have tried to compare the first FIELD with all the lines and try to > pipe it to a new file, but I guess I am missing some syntax thing and want to confirm from experts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be very easily done using `awk`

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ value[$1]; next} $1 in value || FNR < 5'
```

**Test**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{ value[$1]; next} $1 in value || FNR < 5' file2 file1
Model related text
Model specifications
*ELEMENT_SHELL
$#   eid     pid   n1   n2   n3   n4   n5   n6      n7    n8
76737    1    79322  79323   79324   79511     0       0       0       0
76738    1   79510   79203   79204   79512     0       0       0       0
76739    1   79511   79324   79325   79513     0       0       0       0
76740    1   79512   79204   79205   79514     0       0       0       0
76741    1   79514   79205   79206   79515     0       0       0       0
```

---

If you are not interested in the leading headers in the output, the script can be further simplified as

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ value[$1]; next} $1 in value' file2 file1
76737    1    79322  79323   79324   79511     0       0       0       0
76738    1   79510   79203   79204   79512     0       0       0       0
76739    1   79511   79324   79325   79513     0       0       0       0
76740    1   79512   79204   79205   79514     0       0       0       0
76741    1   79514   79205   79206   79515     0       0       0       0
```

**What it does?**

- `FNR==NR` Checks if the number of records read from the current file is equal to total number of records read. Basically this evaluates true only for the first file, that is here for `file2`
- `value[$1]; next` Creates an associative array indexed by `$1`, the value from the `file2`
- `$1 in value` checks if the column 1 is present in the associative array

---

**EDIT**

Print only the first occurence.

You can use `delete` to remove the entry from the associative array once the line has been printed. This ensures that the line is not printed for the second occurence.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ value[$1]; next} $1 in value{ print; delete value[$1] }'
```

Comment: is it possible to limit the output to the first match only? I mean if a certain number appears two times then only the first entry should be considered? I have just seen that in my 10000 lines long file, the Id appears two times and the second appearence is also showing up in my result. Can we get arround with that?

Comment: @hamadhassan Yes it's possible. see the edit. Hope it helps you.